# How to trigger/Update refresh Data from website

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hi I am using the following code to parsing some data from website to excel , I need to create  a routine in order to update /Refresh the data and keep is up to date and I been advice to start  new topic , is big list  with multiple sheets so take long time every time excel  has to calculate , I hope someone can may help me out

```
 Public Function giveMeValue(ByVal link As Variant) As Variant

Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "GET", link, False
   .send
   htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

If Not htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount") Is Nothing Then

   giveMeValue = htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount").innerText

Else
    giveMeValue = "0"

End If

htm.Close
Set htm = Nothing

End Function
```

to retrive the value I use `=GiveMeValue(A1)` and condition  formatting the returned value I use the Following code :

```
Dim color As Integer 'Start Color range

  For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("M4:M5000")

    If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
    If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo nextcell:

    If cell.Value > 14 Then
      color = 4
    ElseIf cell.Value < 8 Then color = 3
    Else: color = 6
    End If
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = color
nextcell:
  Next cell

End Sub
```

so as I am not skilled at all with VBA I may unappropriate use the following code to try get refresh it but without result:

```
Sub Refresh()
Dim WAIT As Double
WAIT = Timer
While Timer < WAIT + 10
DoEvents 'do nothing'
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Wend
MsgBox "Update Finished Successfully !"

'End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds ambitious. I like it! :)

For a start can you just use conditional formatting? Will be a lot quicker than looping through every cell and changing colour.

Secondly, make your GiveMeValue function "volatile" (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html) so that it refreshes every time you recalculate the page i.e. add a line "application.volatile(true) before anything else in the function.

Thirdly: run your refresh code in the "worksheet_calculate" event and change it to:

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim WAIT As Double
    WAIT = Timer
    While Timer < WAIT + 10
        DoEvents 'do nothing'
    Wend
    wsSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

So it runs... waits a bit... calculates, then that calculation triggers another wait... etc... Now that your function is volatile, it should refresh all the "getvalue" formulas you have on the current sheet...

And I guess forthly put a "wsSheet.calculate" in the worksheet_activate event to trigger start of that endless loop...

Having said all that, perhaps that endless loop will cause huge issues i.e. mega computer slow down, inability to use computer, and general doom... only one way to find out! The doevents thing should in theory make everything OK. Maybe add  `if activesheet.codename = "wsSheet" then...` so its only running when you're on that sheet...

Comment: Hi Simon Thank you for  your advice  , I am unable to use the Formatting condition  because the return value is not Text but as string so  I had to include some extra code to condition the value .
Volatile function I tried to include it in the beginning but  as you wondered was causing issue to the pc overloading all the memory and having problem with the other programs. I try to add it again and I would really appreciate if you can advice more detailed about the 'if activesheet.codename = "wsSheet" then...' as mentioned in my post I am not skilled in VBA and ths can solve my problem THX

Comment: 'wsSheet.Calculate' return error object not defined

Comment: So in VBA click "view project explorer" and "view properties window"... You'll see your worksheet objects listed under "Microsoft Excel Objects" something like "Sheet1 (Sheet1)", "Sheet2 (Sheet2)" etc... The first bit is the codename, the second bit is the Excel name or tab name... Click on your sheet and look in the "properties" box: it has a field ambigously  called "(Name)"... This is where you can change that codename to anything you like... Then you can reference it in your code as such... i.e. if you change it to "wsHorse" then your code can use "ThisWorkbook.wsHorse" ...

Comment: PS in your conditional formatting, use a formula "=value(A1) > 5" etc... that will let you compare the cell as if it were a number rather than text

PPS how many instances of that givemevalue formula do you have on the sheet?

Comment: I have around 200/250 instance on every sheet